# numpy's equivalent of MATLAB's (vectorized) sub2ind(..., I, J)

Tags: numpy, indexing

Suppose that `I` and `J` are column vectors, (both of length *K*, say), such that for valid index k, the k-th entries of `I` and `J` represent row and column coordinates in some N-by-N matrix `MAT`.

With MATLAB, to assign to the positions in `MAT` with coordinates corresponding to the positions specified by `I` and `J`, one can write:

```
MAT(sub2ind([N N], I, J)) = X;
```

...where `X` is some vector having length *K*.

With numpy, the best I can come up with is

```
MAT.flat[[np.ravel_multi_index((I[k], J[k]), (N, N)) for k in range(K)]] = X
```

Is there more "colloquial numpy" way to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is much easier than that with numpy.

```
i = I.ravel()
j = J.ravel()
MAT[i,j] = X
```

I used the `ravel` method to convert the columns into one-dimensional arrays.  An alternative is

```
MAT[I.flat, J.flat] = X
```

I can't say for sure without seeing the full context, but I suspect you could modify the code that creates `I` and `J` to make them one-dimensional arrays (i.e. with shape `(K,)`) instead of columns with shape `(K, 1)`.  If you did that, you could just write

```
MAT[I,J] = X
```